# Chromium browser displays blank screen

Tags: chrome, arm, xubuntu

Xubuntu 11.10 oneiric armel
Asus eee pad slider sl101 nvidia-tegra 2 arm tablet
chromium browser 18.0.1025.151

Browsers which work fine are:

- Midori
- Epiphany
- Firefox

Opening a link in Chromium actually I can see the websites are loading but nothing is being displayed on the page...

Even the Chromium settings load as a blank screen.

I tried installing both the Precise and Oneiric Chromium-browser packages. Both give me the same problem.

I deleted the `/home/<user>/.config/chromium` folder and still get a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

Searching on the net i found [this](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-934284.html?sid=5fe9043db542881f42c52434f644c3a1).

The problem seems to be to haven't SYSVIPC:

```
grep -E 'CONFIG_SYSVIPC|CONFIG_SHMEM' /usr/src/linux/.config
```

Comment: Weird bug and good to know, but not the case here unless Joshua recompiled his kernel. SysV IPC is pretty much necessary on anything that isn't a single-purpose embedded system. With Ubuntu packages, the kernel configuration is in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`.