# Chromium does not Render webpage (arm)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome, arm

I am trying to run Chromium (the browser) on a Ubuntu install within Android (ARM) and am facing a weird issue: Webpages are not rendering at all.

Links etc within the page are still clickable, however the webpage area is completely blank.

[image]

Terminal output:

```
chromium-browser --user-data-dir='/home/zac'
[2495:2495:0710/143156:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(192)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2495:2495:0710/143156:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(192)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2495:2495:0710/143156:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(192)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2495:2495:0710/143156:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(212)] Gdk: shmget failed: error 38 (Function not implemented)
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
Failed to open /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you need any more info, let me know!

Comment: Is android Unix, I know it has a Linux kernel, but I think this site uses “Linux” to mean “Gnu+Linux”.

Comment: Sorry I am isrunning an install of Ubuntu within Android (Chroot) edited to avoid confusion

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46998/chromium-browser-displays-blank-screen?rq=1

Comment: I do not have  /usr/src/linux/.config

Comment: Add to your question the output of running chromium trough the terminal.

Comment: Added to question